# Test Controller layer of an Express Typescript application with Jest and Supertest

Tags: typescript, express, unit-testing, jestjs, supertest

I'm currently looking for a way to unit test the controller layer of my express typescript application. I'm using layered architecture model with request pattern going through controller -> service -> repository.

I have successfully tested service and repository layers with jest. Now to test controllers, I think we can't basically unit test it, instead need to do some sort of integration type testing. I used super-test in addition to jest. But I'm struggling to get the test setup going. Can anyone help me how to set it up and test an API method. Thanks.

**index (Entry point of server)**

```
const StartServer = async () => {

    // initialize the application server
    const app: Application = express();
    
    await expressApp(app);

    // listen to the application server on PORT
    let server = http.createServer(app);
    server.listen(0, (): void => {
        console.log(`Express application server running on address=> http://localhost:${server.address().port}`);
    });
}

StartServer();

module.exports = StartServer;
```

**Express App (Have the routing)**

```
module.exports = async (app: Application) => {
    
    // configuring necessary properties for server
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

    // cors
    await corsConfig(app);
    

    // auth configurations
    await authConfig(app);

    // routes definition
    app.use("/api/v1/roles", RoleRouter);

    // error handling
    await errorHandler(app);
}
```

**Router**

```
const RoleRouter = express.Router();
const roleController = new RoleController();

RoleRouter.post("/", roleController.createRole);

export default RoleRouter;
```

**RoleController (Testing file)**

```
export class RoleController {

    private static roleService: RoleService = new RoleService();
    private static permissionService: PermissionService = new PermissionService();
    private static logger: Logger<unknown> = new Logger();

    public async createRole(req: Request<{}, {}, RoleCreateRequestDto>, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> {
        const requestDto = plainToClass(RoleCreateRequestDto, req.body);
        if (!requestDto.isRequiredAvailable()) {
            RoleController.logger.error("Required fields missing in role create request DTO for creating role");
            res.status(ErrorResponseStatusType.MISSING_REQUIRED_FIELDS.getProperty(ResponseStatusTypeProperty.CODE))
            .send(getErrorResponseWrapper(ErrorResponseStatusType.MISSING_REQUIRED_FIELDS));
        }

        try {
            const permissions = new Array<Permission>();
            requestDto.getProperty(DtoProperty.PERMISSIONS).forEach(async (permissionType: { toString: () => string; }) => {
                const permission = await RoleController.permissionService.findByPermission(permissionType.toString());
                permissions.push(permission);
            });

            const role = new Role(requestDto, permissions);
            await RoleController.roleService.createRole(role);

            const roleResponseDto = new RoleResponseDto(role);

            RoleController.logger.info("Successfully created the role, responseDto: ", roleResponseDto.toJson());
            res.status(SuccessResponseStatusType.CREATE_ROLE.getProperty(ResponseStatusTypeProperty.CODE))
            .send(getSuccessResponseWrapper(SuccessResponseStatusType.CREATE_ROLE, roleResponseDto));
        } catch (e) {
            next(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**RoleController.test.ts**

```
import request from 'supertest';
import { Express } from "express-serve-static-core";
const StartServer = require('../../src/index');

let server: Express;



jest.mock('../../src/services/RoleService', () => {
    return {
        RoleService: jest.fn(),
    }
});
jest.mock('../../src/services/PermissionService', () => {
    return {
        PermissionService: jest.fn(),
    }
});



let mockedRoleService: jest.Mock;
let mockedPermissionService: jest.Mock;
let RoleControllerInstance: RoleController;
mockedRoleService = RoleService as jest.Mock;
mockedPermissionService = PermissionService as jest.Mock;


beforeAll(async () => {
    server = await StartServer();
})


describe('RoleController, createRole method', () => {
    const permission = new Permission();
    let mockedRoleServiceCreateRole: jest.Mock;
    mockedRoleServiceCreateRole = jest.fn();
    let mockedPermissionServiceFindByPermission: jest.Mock;
    mockedPermissionServiceFindByPermission = jest.fn();

    beforeEach(() => {
        mockedPermissionService.mockReturnValue({
            findByPermission: mockedPermissionServiceFindByPermission,
        });
        mockedRoleService.mockReturnValue({
            createRole: mockedRoleServiceCreateRole,
        });
        RoleControllerInstance = new RoleController();
    });

    test('Should return status 201, when creating role is successful', async () => {
        mockedPermissionServiceFindByPermission.mockResolvedValue(permission);

        const response = await request(server).post('/api/v1/roles')
            .send({
                role: "SUPER_ADMIN",
                permissions: [
                    "CREATE_USER", "UPDATE_USER", "DELETE_USER", "SUSPEND_USER",
                    "UPDATE_PROFILE", "CREATE_ROLE", "UPDATE_ROLE", "DELETE_ROLE"
                ]
            });

        expect(response.status).toBe(201);
    });
})
```

Is this setup is right?? Also when I try to run the test like this. I get an error like
[image: Error]